# Error with `glmer{lme4}`: cannot coerce class "family" to a data.frame

Tags: r, regression, lme4

I am running a generalized linear model with random effects using the `glmer()` function from the package `lme4`.

The model code looks like this:

```
mod6 <- glmer((Ndifference+74337) ~ netm1011 + d1011 + 
           b0001 + (1|region), Gamma(link = "identity"))
```

`Ndifference` is count data of population differences between 200 and 2010 of 50 states (and DC). There is one negative value (Michigan at -74336) so I added a constant to make sure my response was all positive.

All the predictors (aside from the random effect of region) are proportions or percentages. Netm1011 (rate of immigration to the states in 2010) and d1011 (rate of deaths per 1000 people) both have several negative values. B0001 contains all positive proportions (birth rate/1000 people).

When I run the model I keep getting this error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
  cannot coerce class ""family"" to a data.frame
```

I've tried different families of distributions as well (`Gamma`, `inverse.gaussian`). What exactly does this error code mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
glmer(formula, data = NULL, family = gaussian, control = glmerControl(),
      start = NULL, verbose = 0L, nAGQ = 1L, subset, weights, na.action,
      offset, contrasts = NULL, mustart, etastart,
      devFunOnly = FALSE, ...)
```

You want to specify formal argument, too:

```
family = Gamma(link = "identity")
```

When no formal argument is specified, argument is matched by position. The 2nd argument is `data`, but you passed `Gamma` function to it. So `model.frame` can not work.

**This may be a specific issue to `glmer`.** Compare with `glm`:

```
glm(formula, family = gaussian, data, weights, subset,
    na.action, start = NULL, etastart, mustart, offset,
    control = list(...), model = TRUE, method = "glm.fit",
    x = FALSE, y = TRUE, contrasts = NULL, ...)
```

The 2nd argument is `family` and `data` is the 3rd. So there will be no problem is you do:

```
glm((Ndifference+74337) ~ netm1011 + d1011, Gamma(link = "identity"))
```

Also consider `gam` from `mgcv`:

```
gam(formula,family=gaussian(),data=list(),weights=NULL,subset=NULL,
    na.action,offset=NULL,method="GCV.Cp",
    optimizer=c("outer","newton"),control=list(),scale=0,
    select=FALSE,knots=NULL,sp=NULL,min.sp=NULL,H=NULL,gamma=1,
    fit=TRUE,paraPen=NULL,G=NULL,in.out,drop.unused.levels=TRUE,
    drop.intercept=NULL,...)
```

We see the `family` is at 2nd position, too.

Comment: Hi @Zheyuan_Li , thanks for the update, so I ended up inserting the family argument and ran the model, which resulted in a huge matrix and an error code reading: 
    Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate

Comment: Hi @Zheyuan Li , thank you again. I ended up hanging the title to reflect on this error as well as the question itself. I also acknowledged you for answering the first error issue involving the family argument. Quick question, how do I even attach data to my posts?

Comment: I had a follow up question on your previous comment. so once i utilize the dput function.... should i copy and paste this into my new post?

Comment: I am still figuring out how to get my data on my new question! I definitely will be posting a new one as soon as I figure this out!

Comment: Will do. Thanks and sorry for all the trouble